# How to get an Angular component template

Tags: c#, angular

In our SaaS, we want to have different component templates for each customer, and have a editor to change the component template for each of them.

We're able to do so like this :

let viewContainerRef = this.anchorHost.viewContainerRef;

```
    const tenant = this.getTenant();
    var template = "";

    if (tenant == TenantList.1)
        template = "<h1>1 TEMPLATE</h1>";
    else if (tenant == TenantList.2)
        template = "<h1>2 TEMPLATE</h1>";
    else {
        //Load template Default template ( The one from the component)
    }        
    
    var tmpComponent = Component({ template: template })(HomeDefaultComponent);            
    const tmpModule = NgModule({ declarations: [tmpComponent] })(class { });

    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
        .then((factories) => {
            const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
            const cmpRef = f.create(this.injector, [], null, this.m);
            cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';

            viewContainerRef.clear();
            viewContainerRef.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
        })
```

But we don't know how to load the component default template that is in the file system. Is that possible?
Perhaps this is not the right approach?

Comment: If I am not wrong these templates will contain more or less same blocks/elements. You can create a if/else structural directive in template (*ngIf/else)

Comment: Thats not what we need, we need to be able to have completely different templates between tenants